# How can i add incoming audio stream into existing audio stream while recording

Tags: javascript, webrtc

i am trying to add audio from incoming peers in mid of recording . I'm using a media recorder and passing a media stream to it . and if there is some new peer joins then i want to join his audio into recorder

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.